# set jquery mobile attributes in rails paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-mobile, will-paginate

I have a mobile page for my app that uses the jquery mobile "collapsible" data-role to hide Microposts (Hartl's tutorial) until the user clicks them to expand.

I also use a modified paginate to render the paginate links.
https://gist.github.com/jugyo/3135120

```
<div data-role="collapsible">
  <h3>Show Microposts (<%= @user.microposts.count %>)</h3>
  <ul data-role="listview">
    <%= render @microposts %>
  </ul>
  <%= will_paginate @microposts, 
    renderer: WillPaginate::ActionView::JqueryMobilePaginateLinkRenderer,
    previous_label: 'Prev',
    next_label: 'Next'
  %>
</div>
```

My question is: how do I add an event to the paginate click? I want to have the list collapsed (the default), with data-role="collapsible" when the page is first loaded, but when I click next (or later, prev) I want the collapsible container to add the data-collapsed="false" attribute so that the list is open.
(It doesn't make sense to click next and go to a collapsed list again)

Do I put it in the rb that has the paginate code? If so, how do I refer to the page elements? Or do I put some jquery somewhere...?

Any assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `class` or `id` to your pagination. I'll add an `id` :

```
<%= will_paginate @microposts, 
  renderer: WillPaginate::ActionView::JqueryMobilePaginateLinkRenderer,
  id: 'my_pagination',
  previous_label: 'Prev',
  next_label: 'Next'
%>
```

Then give your main div some kind of identifier :

```
<div data-role="collapsible" id="my_list">
```

Now you can activate it manually with jQuery :

```
$("#my_pagination").click(function() { 
    $("#my_list").data("collapsed", $("#my_list").data('collapsed') == 'false' ? 'true' : 'false') 
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Trip. I had a go at this at work today and the jQuery was getting called (checked with alert()), but wasn't holding the list open. In your answer, when you say: "your_list.data", do I get that through an id on the ul? (Didn't work), or...
Sorry, can you fill in the gaps for me here a little.

Comment: Ah I just figured out what `my_list` was and updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks heaps. I'll have a crack at this tomorrow.

Comment: Hmmm. This is still not working for me. By inspecting the page in Firebug, I can see that id: 'my_pagination', does not add the id anywhere in the page. I found the .trigger("expand") method on the jquery mobile site: jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/content/content-collapsible-methods.html, and am trying to trigger it by selecting on $("div.ui-grid-a") which is where the nav buttons are, but it's not working either. Let me know if you have any more suggestions... :)

Comment: Hmmm.. instead of adding an ID selector, try adding a class selector with `class:` to the pagination block..